# How to get synonyms of word from DB(EF, linq)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a structure like this:

```
================
tranlation
================
langid1
originalword
langid2
translationword
```

originalword and translationword are synonyms when in translation `langid == langid`.

I want to find all synonyms of word.

For example: we have a table of translations(in all these translations `langid1 == langid 2`):

```
1. group bunch
2. group set
3. suite group
```

I need to get synonyms of word "suite"
The result may be "group, bunch, set"
or I need to get synonyms of word "group"
The result may be "bunch, set, suite"

I use Entity framework code first.

How to do a query to pull these synonyms?

Comment: @Micky nothing. i don't know how to do that at all. I can write a query that pull for "suite" one synonym "group", but i need all synonyms. to do that i need recursive query, even if i find out how to do recursive query i need to store array of synonyms that have been found already to prepare infinity recursive loop, but query to DB doesn't allow to use outside array in query to make sure that this synonym already found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with a single query. But the following combination of EF query and client processing will do the job:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(IQueryable<Translation> translation, string word)
{
    var baseQuery = translation.Where(t => t.langid == t.langid2);
    var filter = new HashSet<string> { word };
    var query = (from t in baseQuery where filter.Contains(t.originalword) && !filter.Contains(t.translationword) select t.translationword)
        .Union(from t in baseQuery where filter.Contains(t.translationword) && !filter.Contains(t.originalword) select t.originalword);
    var processed = new HashSet<string> { word };
    var next = new List<string>();
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            if (processed.Add(item))
            {
                yield return item;
                next.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (next.Count == 0) break;
        filter.Clear();
        foreach (var item in next)
            filter.Add(item);
        next.Clear();
    }
}
```

Sample test:

```
class Translation
{
    public int langid { get; set; }
    public string originalword { get; set; }
    public int langid2 { get; set; }
    public string translationword { get; set; }
}

static void Test()
{
    var translation = new List<Translation>
    {
        new Translation { originalword = "group", translationword = "bunch" },
        new Translation { originalword = "group", translationword = "set" },
        new Translation { originalword = "suite", translationword = "group" },
    }
    .AsQueryable();

    var s1 = GetSynonyms(translation, "group").ToList();
    var s2 = GetSynonyms(translation, "suite").ToList();
    var s3 = GetSynonyms(translation, "bunch").ToList();
    var s4 = GetSynonyms(translation, "set").ToList();
    var s5 = GetSynonyms(translation, "blah").ToList();
}
```

Your usage could be something like this

```
YourDbContext db = ...;
var suiteSynonyms = GetSynonyms(db.Translation, "suite");
```